# wkhtmltopdf center the document

Tags: shell, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to print an html document into a pdf file using wkhtmltopdf.
How do I pass the parameters to print this html document in the middle of the page?
currently I run it with :

```
wkhtmltopdf -O Landscape -s A5 fileName.html fileName.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can center the document horizontally by adding simple CSS to its HTML `body` tag:

```
<body style="text-align: center">
```